# How to get administration views to work?

Tags: views, nodes

As my content began to expand into a large repository I started to miss the feature of being able to filter content by a simple "title contains" criterion. I found out Administration Views that got installed by Admin Menu. However, the content view is contaminated by a [known bug](http://drupal.org/node/1282094). It allegedly comes from incompatibility with VBO. This prevents the view from functioning or being edited.

Is anyone successfully running admin views, caring to list the module versions for Views, VBO, Admin Menu?

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure your problem is already gone by now but for those who might be searching for ways to make [Admin Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/admin_views) and [VBO](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations) work, the versions I'm using are [7.x-1.3](https://www.drupal.org/node/2276117) and [7.x-3.2](https://www.drupal.org/node/2161705) respectively.

You would need to [clear Drupal cache](https://www.drupal.org/node/42055) for the default admin pages to be overridden by the newly added Admin Views.